# How do I display the value of a Django form field in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a form with an email property.

When using `{{ form.email }}` in case of some validation error, Django still renders the previous value in the input tag's value attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="id_email" maxlength="75" class="required"
       value="some@email.com" name="email">
```

I want to render the input tag myself (to add some JavaScript code and an error class in case of an error). For example this is my template instead of `{{ form.email }}`:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" id="id_email" name="email"
       class="email {% if form.email.errors %} error {% endif %}">
```

However, this does not display the erroneous value (`some@email.com` in this example) to the user.

How do I get the field's value in the template?

Comment: The documentation has some useful examples for [working with form templates.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution proposed by Jens is correct.
However, it turns out that if you initialize your ModelForm with an *instance* (example below) django will not populate the data:

```
def your_view(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserDetailsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          # some code here   
        else:
          form = UserDetailsForm(instance=request.user)
```

So, I made my own ModelForm base class that populates the initial data:

```
from django import forms 
class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Subclass of `forms.ModelForm` that makes sure the initial values
    are present in the form data, so you don't have to send all old values
    for the form to actually validate.
    """
    def merge_from_initial(self):
        filt = lambda v: v not in self.data.keys()
        for field in filter(filt, getattr(self.Meta, 'fields', ())):
            self.data[field] = self.initial.get(field, None)
```

Then, the simple view example looks like this:

```
def your_view(request):   if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserDetailsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      # some code here   
    else:
      form = UserDetailsForm(instance=request.user)
      form.merge_from_initial()
```

Comment: I don't see why django isn't doing this by default...  I think I'll submit a patch and see what people say about it.

Answer (score 150):

This was a feature request that got fixed in Django 1.3.

Here's the bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427

Basically, if you're running something after 1.3, in Django templates you can do:

```
{{ form.field.value|default_if_none:"" }}
```

Or in Jinja2:

```
{{ form.field.value()|default("") }}
```

Note that `field.value()` is a method, but in Django templates `()`'s are omitted, while in Jinja2 method calls are explicit.

If you want to know what version of Django you're running, it will tell you when you do the runserver command.

If you are on something prior to 1.3, you can probably use the fix posted in the above bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427#comment:24

Comment: This is the right answer for Django >= 1.3. This was conspicuously absent from the django documentation, but that now looks to have been fixed (at least in the dev version). https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16851

Comment: This has the nasty effect that if `form.field.value` is `None`, then the text "None" will be displayed. To display an empty string instead, use `{{ form.field.value|default_if_none:"" }}`

Comment: +1 for mentioning this works in >=1.3 only. I'm still running 1.2, and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working until I read this.

Comment: Working with `{{ form.initial.fieldname }}` here (Django 1.2.3).

Comment: I could be wrong @santiagopim, but I believe that will give you the initial value every time, instead of giving you the value the user input. For example, make a form that throws an error instead of being submitted, and you'll see that the user's input switched to the initial value after the submission, rather than keeping the user's input.

Comment: The part where you wrote `{{ form.field.value|default_if_none:"" }}` , how can I pass a for loop object in the `value`  part ? Somebody put up a question just to ask this! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412392/insert-for-loop-item-in-django-output-field)

Comment: You should be handling that part in your view or your form.

Answer (score 51):

You can do this from the template with something like this:

```
{% if form.instance.some_field %}
      {{form.instance.some_field}}
{% else %}
      {{form.data.some_field}}
{% endif %}
```

This will display the instance value (if the form is created with an instance, you can use initial instead if you like), or else display the POST data such as when a validation error occurs.

Comment: a shame this answer is buried so deep! This is the way to do it without adding any code to your project or patching your django.

Comment: Can you expand on what I'm filling in to those made up fields? I tried a few variations and it has not worked.

Answer (score 20):

I have a simple solution for you!

```
{{ form.data.email }}
```

I tried this and it worked. This requires your view to populate the form class with the POST data.

Very simple example:

```
def your_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      # some code here
  else:
    form = YourForm()

  return render_to_response('template.html', {'form':form})
```

Hope that helps you. If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: The cleaned data will not contain the email field if it couldn't be cleaned during validation.

Comment: You are right. You won't be able to access cleaned_data if is_valid() fails. I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: I updated my code. There was a simple solution. Instead of cleaned_data simply use data. That worked even if the validation fails!

Comment: data doesn't work for me...
{{ form.description }}  gives a control with correct value
{{ form.data.description }} is empty (in fact, {{ form.data }} returns {})

Comment: btw, I'm initializing the form by doing: form_details = forms.UserDetailsForm(instance=request.user)

Comment: I am not sure your answer is upto the question. Anyway,  `{{ form.data }}` gives a dict. From which we can process the data from server side. I was looking for this one for some reason. Now i can change the value from server side, like `form.data[stringvaluecorrespondingtofield] = newstringvalue `.

Comment: @eran-kampf You get a dict with all the data associated with form. You can process the data. **I am working in Django 1.6**

Answer (score 18):

This seems to work.

```
{{ form.fields.email.initial }}
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe that will show the initial value every time. For example, try submitting the form so it throws an error and you'll see that the form that reloads showing the error will have the initial value again, not the value the user put in before it threw the error.

Answer (score 14):

`{{ form.field_name.value }}` works for me

Comment: Depends on your version. That works in Django 1.3. New feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value

Comment: This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). For a Django `ModelAdmin` template, use `adminform.form`, for example: `{{ adminform.form.field_name.value }}`.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to display the value of a formset field. I concluded this solution, which should work for normal forms too:

```
{% if form.email.data %} {{ form.email.data }}
{% else %} {{ form.initial.email }} 
{% endif %}
```

The above solutions didn't worked very well for me, and I doubt they would work in case of prefixed forms (such as wizards and formsets).
The solutions using `{{ form.data.email }}` can't work, because it is a dictionary lookup, and with prefixed forms your field name would look something like '1-email' (wizard and prefixed form) or 'form-1-email' (formset), and the minus sign (-) are not allowed in dotted template lookup expressions.

`{{form.field_name.value}}` is Django 1.3+ only.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few of the mentioned possibilities, and this is how I solved my problem:

```
#forms.py
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name',
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                 required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name',
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                 required=False)
    # username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    #                              attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    #                              required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                 required=False)
    phoneNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=11,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                 required=False)
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Change Profile Image', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['photo', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phoneNumber', 'address']
                  # 'username',



#views.py
def edit_user_profile(request, username):
    user = request.user
    username = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user_extended_photo = UserExtended.objects.get(user=user.id)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=user)
    user_extended = UserExtended.objects.get(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # photo = UserExtended(photo=request.FILES['photo'] or None, )
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user_extended.address = request.POST['address']
            user_extended.phoneNumber = request.POST['phoneNumber']
            user_extended.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
            # username = request.POST['username']
            user_extended.save()
            user.save()

            context = {
                'form': form,
                'username': username,
                'user_extended_photo': user_extended_photo,
            }

            return render(request, 'accounts/profile_updated.html', context)
    else:
        photo = user_extended.photo
        first_name = user.first_name
        last_name = user.last_name
        address = user_extended.address
        phoneNumber = user_extended.phoneNumber
        form = EditProfileForm(
            initial={'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name,
                                   'address': address, 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
                                   'photo': photo})
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'username': username,
        'user_extended_photo': user_extended_photo,

    }
    return render_to_response('accounts/edit_profile.html', context,
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#edit_profile.html
  <form action="/accounts/{{ user.username }}/edit_profile/" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                {{ form.as_p }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                                    <button type="submit"  value="Update Profile" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Update Profile</button>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
```

I am trying to explain this in a way so that beginners may find it easier to understand. Pay close attention to the `else:`

```
        photo = user_extended.photo
        first_name = user.first_name
        last_name = user.last_name
        address = user_extended.address
        phoneNumber = user_extended.phoneNumber
        form = EditProfileForm(
            initial={'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name,
                                  'address': address, 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
                                  'photo': photo})
```

It is what gets the value attrib, e.g.:

```
<p><label for="id_first_name">First Name:</label> <input class="form-control" id="id_first_name" name="first_name" type="text" value="Emmanuel" /></p>
<p><label for="id_last_name">Last Name:</label> <input class="form-control" id="id_last_name" name="last_name" type="text" value="Castor" /></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've populated the form with an instance and not with POST data (as the suggested answer requires), you can access the data using {{ form.instance.my_field_name }}.

Answer (score 1):

For check box with its items:

```
{% for item in people.q %}
    <div class="form-check form-switch ">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.id_for_label }}">{{ item.data.label }}</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{ item.id_for_label }}" value="{{ item.data.value }}">
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

q is field name.

Answer (score 0):

On Django 1.2, {{ form.data.field }} and {{ form.field.data }} are all OK, but not {{ form.field.value }}.
As others said, {{ form.field.value }} is Django 1.3+ only, but there's no specification in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/. It can be found in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/.

Answer (score -2):

```
{{form.fields.email}}
```

Comment: This gives: 
<django.forms.fields.RegexField object at 0x083235B0>

Comment: You can write a filter to fetch the value.

Comment: there's no built-in way to get it?