# Django: Display values of the selected multiple choice field in a template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to find a way of displaying the text of the selected/initial value of a multiple choice field.

My question is similar to this one except I don't want the *value* I want to the option text it corresponds to:

[Display value of a django form field in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template)

For example if I had a form with the following:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('male', _('Men')),
    ('female', _('Women')),
)

genders = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
    widget=widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    initial=[gender[0] for gender in GENDER_CHOICES])
```

then in my template I can do:

```
{{ form.genders.value }}
```

to get an array of selected options (i.e. [u'male', u'female']. However, I somehow want to look up the string value from the key (i.e. "Men", "Women"), something like:

```
{% for key in form.genders.value %}
    {{ form.genders.choices.key }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't find a way of making this work. How can I achieve this using Django 1.3?

ps - This is a short example, but I need to do it with bigger dynamic lists that prohibit using multiple if statements (i.e. "if key == 'male' 'Men' ... etc")

Comment: This could probably be something like: `{% for key in form.genders.value %}
    {{ form.genders.get_key_display }}
{% endfor %}` But I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Add a method to the form**, that returns the list that you want
2. **Call it from the template**

It looks like this:

```
def selected_genders_labels(self):
    return [label for value, label in self.fields['genders'].choices if value in self['genders'].value()]
```

In action:

```
In [1]: from testapp.views import XForm; f = XForm(initial={'genders': ['male', 'female']}); print f.selected_genders_labels()
['Men', 'Women']

In [2]: from testapp.views import XForm; f = XForm(initial={'genders': ['female']}); print f.selected_genders_labels()
['Women']

In [3]: from testapp.views import XForm; f = XForm(initial={'genders': []}); print f.selected_genders_labels()
[]

In [4]: from testapp.views import XForm; f = XForm(); print f.selected_genders_labels()
['Men', 'Women']
```

So you can just iterate like this:

```
{% for label in form.selected_genders_labels %}
    {{ label }}
{% endfor %}
```

FTR, i used:

```
class XForm(forms.Form):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('male', 'Men'),
        ('female', 'Women'),
    )

    genders = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        widget=widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        initial=[gender[0] for gender in GENDER_CHOICES])

    def selected_genders_labels(self):
        return [label for value, label in self.fields['genders'].choices if value in self['genders'].value()]
```

You can make such a template filter:

```
@register.filter
def selected_labels(form, field):
    return [label for value, label in form.fields[field].choices if value in form[field].value()]
```

Usage:

```
{% for label in form|selected_labels:"genders" %}
    {{ label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can turn this into a template tag or something? I've got quite a lot of fields I need to do this to and don't really want a method per field...

Comment: You should make a template filter instead, it's much easier.

Comment: Updated with a template filter example.