# django template add old form data

Tags: django, forms, validation, templates

I am making a form but when the data is invalid, it empties the field when loading the page again, how can i solve this?
My view:

```
def create_country(request):

    if request.POST:
        country_form = CountryForm(request.POST)
        if country_form.is_valid():
            country_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('country'))

        else:
            return render(request, 'create_country.html', {'country_form': country_form})

    country_form = CountryForm()
    return render(request, 'create_country.html', {'country_form': country_form})
```

And my template:

```
<div>
    <center>
        <h2>Create a new country</h2>
    </center>
    <form action="{% url 'create_country' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <b>{{ country_form.non_field_errors }}</b>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <b>{{ country_form.name.errors }}</b>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="id_name">Name:</label></td>
                <td><input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" size= "25" maxlength="127" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <b>{{ country_form.flavor.errors }}</b>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="id_flavor">Flavor Text:</label></td>
                <td><textarea style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="id_flavor" type="text" name="flavor" maxlength="511"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td style="float: right;"><input type="submit" value="add country" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can i add my old data thats put in before the post add back into the form after it returns as non valid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template

Comment: Jep that seems to solve it,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the [basic form layouts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) like `{{ form }}` or `{{ form.as_ul }}` do not render the way you want, then have a good read of the docs on  [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template). Using that, you should be able to render the form the way you want using CSS. You could specify the [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances) in your form fields to set any attributes required.

Try to avoid rendering form inputs by hand in your templates. It is repetitive, and increases the chances of making mistakes.

Comment: Damn, i didnt even know about that,  thats my homework for tomorrow :) Thanks