# Retrieving value from a form in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am attempting to obtain a value which is present in a form that is passed to my template. This is what my view does

```
return render(request, 'manageStudent.html',
                  {'form': StudentDetails(
                      initial={
                          'school_name': rslt[0][1],
                          'student_user_name': rslt[0][3],
                      }
                  ),}
```

I am attempting to read the username using the following way in my template

```
 This is the data    {{ form.fields.student_user_name.initial}}
```

However i simply get None in response. I tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template) but none seem to work in my case. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't get it from the form, pass it as a separate parameter to the content.

Comment: I could always do that and that was my last resort. I am curious as to why something so crucial is not easily available ?

Comment: Well, because clearly the developers and users of Django don't think that is crucial. I've certainly never needed it.

Comment: I don't think it's a feature that's necessary. Forms are meant to hide the complexity for handling data, so manually extracting data from form is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{{ form.initial.student_user_name }}
```

That works for me in django 1.7 when I initialize my form using

```
StudentDetails(instance=student_details_obj)
```