# Django Template view url or FileField

Tags: django, forms

I have a model form with

```
file1=forms.FileFiled(required=False)
```

the template shows it fine, with the default widget when using `{{ f.file1 }}` if the form has data from an instance, how can I know the file name and url in the template?

I would like to serve the file myself with a function instead of how django shows it in the template, which does not work.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749842/2011147). You should be able to use a similar approach.

Comment: `{% if f.file1 %}{{ f.name }} - {{ f.url }}{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the relative path doing:

```
{{ f.file1.name }}
```

But don't forget to add in your `setting.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

You can also check the official Django documentation: [FileField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name)

Comment: Thanks, I added the settings details and now file1.name gives me the name of the file now, but not the url. Is it because the path is not in the media folder? these are doc and pdf files. in djangoprojectfolder/files/fileX