# Django request.POST get data from input

Tags: python, django, post

In HTML

```
<form method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.name}}
{{form.email}}
<textarea name='message'>{{form.message}}</textarea>
<button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

How I can get the message data from my textarea in my view? Or the right way is put {{form.as_p}} in form? Please help

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is perfectly alright if you want this on view. Another safe method is `request.POST.get('message')`  it will return `None` instead of error message, if it's available.

But, you want it on template then you can use

```
{{ form.data.message }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` is basically a dictionary returned. It contains `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and all form data with name specified as key in the `request.POST` dict.

So, as per your form, you can get the message data from textarea by simply writing

```
message_data = request.POST['message']
```

in `view.py` .

If you want to display form in your style then do it manually. Otherwise, django provides few techniques to render form, and they are as follows:

`{{ form.as_table }}` will render form as table cells wrapped in `<tr>` tags,

`{{ form.as_p }}` will render form wrapped in `<p>` tags,

`{{ form.as_ul }}` will render form wrapped in `<li>` tags.

Now, it depends upon you, how you want your form to look on page.