# GeoDjango OSMWidget coordinate change

Tags: python, django, django-forms, geodjango

I want to know if there's a way to know when the OSMWidget coordinates have been changed, I'm pretending to reflect this change on the Longitude and Latitude fields. I have the following form:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms
from .models import Branch


class BranchCreateForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label ="Name", max_length=120)
    image_facade = forms.ImageField( label="Image Facade")
    longitude = forms.DecimalField(label = "Latitude", max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    latitude = forms.DecimalField(label = "Longitude", max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    location = forms.PointField(
        widget=forms.OSMWidget(
            attrs={'map_width': 600,
                   'map_height': 400,
                   'template_name': 'gis/openlayers-osm.html',
                   'default_lat': 42.1710962,
                   'default_lon': 18.8062112,
                   'default_zoom': 6}))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `PointField` contains the `longitude` and `latitude` coordinates of the [`Point` object that it creates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.Point). Therefore you don't need to save them separately as `DecimalField`s.

Whenever a change is made through the widget and the form is saved, the `Point` is updated accordingly.

Let's assume that you have a `Branch` instance then you can access the coordinates as follows:

```
br = Branch.objects.get(pk=1)
longitude = br.location.x
latitude = br.location.y
```

---

**EDIT After declaration Provided by OP:**

You don't need to add the fields in the form class.
What you need is to access the specific form fields in the template:

```
{{ form.location.x|default_if_none:"" }}
{{ form.location.y|default_if_none:"" }}
```

Source: [Display value of a django form field in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236691/display-value-of-a-django-form-field-in-a-template)

Comment: The model doesn't have the longitude and latitude fields, I'm just using them in the template, its just for visualization purposes, for example if a user is creating a new branch, and uses the map to change the default point, I want this to be reflected on the latitude and longitude input fields.

Comment: @katbarahona I have updated my answer, does this fit your needs?